# Excel pivot table range and cross reference

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to create a table, preferably a pivot table to count all the number of unique answers from a questionnaire in a range. I can't get this to work in a pivot table. WHich should be columns and rows?

```
And later see:
YES                              74
Not applicable/relevant          57
Calculation logic not accepted   23
and so on...
```

Here is a screenshot: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/240/92q.png

[image: SO 17526626 question example]

---

At stage 2: I want to cross reference two tables (preferably pivot tables) to see, for instance:

Of all answers "Not discussed or shown to customer" answers how many percent of them were from Finance or Procurement?

Like this:
Answers:

```
YES - 74

 1. 55 % Marketing
 2. 35 % Operations
 3. 10 % Finance

Not applicable/relevant - 57

 1. 100 % Finance

Calculation logic not accepted - 23

 1. 65 % Technology
 2. 35 % Procurement
```

Comment: Maybe unclear, anyone?

Comment: If you can upload or share a copy of this file, I'm sure I can help you out.