# Get total figure from multiple figures in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a spread sheet with data on it that I am trying to add up to get a grand total for each week and month.

The data is displayed within a single sheet/tab on excel that has a date column and goes back to lets say 1st December. What im trying to do is add each total up to basically get a weekly and monthly figure instead of a figure for each individual day.

For example sake lets say im trying to add up the weekly total of apples picked for each person.

```
A1 = EMPLOYEE ID
B1 = DATE APPLES WERE PICKED 
C1 = how many apples were picked on that 1 day
```

The hard bit is there is 100 people each day picking these so its hundreds of lines of data.

Im wanting to get a total weekly amount for each person but its hard to do as there are too many employees so I cant do it by manually working it out

### Output basically looks like that

```
A1 20332332
B1 FROM 10/2/16 - 17/02/16
C1 312 (APPLES PICKED)
A2 888865
B2 FROM 10/2/16 - 17/02/16
C2 222 (APPLES PICKED)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try to do it with **Pivot Table** (here I use Excel 2010, but it exist in previous releases)

First select your data and go to the insert pane:

[image: select data]

Then Ok
[image: just OK]

Finally check the date and "number of apples" fields:
[image: check fields]

See [Excel pivot table range and cross reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526626/excel-pivot-table-range-and-cross-reference) for more.

To better meet your need, add 2 columns, one being "month", the other being "year" and calculated from DATE. You must put the "number of apple" column in the "sum" subwindow (lower left).
Here is what I get for example:
[image: example]